# Memcache global expiration change

Tags: caching, memcached

Is it possible to change all the key/value pairs in memcache instances with a command line?

Say, I have 10 memcache servers and they have key value pairs, and they all have the objects with 30 days expiration. But they don't expire at the same time, and I don't want all of them to expire at the same time. I want to change the objects to expire in 10 days. How can I make this change?

Is this even possible?

Can this be done via a commandline? Do I have to write a program for this?

Comment: Memcache intentionally has a very simple expiration mechanism. It's designed around very fast caching of recoverable data. What is your application doing that it requires coherent expiration across servers?

Comment: @ssamuel I m migrating data between data sources and some of the data is being updated. i want the cache to expire for a period then i want it to be re-populated from the new data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by touching values periodically. The FAQ [describes a way to do this](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingTricks#%22Touching%22_keys_with_add).

However, memcache isn't designed for this. What you're doing seems to be more like a persistent cache scenario. If you love memcache semantics, [Membase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membase) and [MemcacheDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MemcacheDB) provide solutions that may better fit your needs. There are *many* different persistent cache systems that do this just as well.

Depending on your specs, sometimes speeding up your data source may deliver better performance than memcache. Modern DMBSs cache heavily with sensible access protocols. This is entirely dependent on what your data sources look like and how much flexibility you have in your system design.

Answer (score 0):

Memcache has a telnet interface. Then you can use `FLUSH_ALL` or `FLUSH_ALL <seconds_to_wait>`, if that's what you mean...

Comment: sorry to hear that. I assume you telneted to there server and the command didn't expire the items? could you provide some more info?

Comment: no such assumption. i dont want to flush the whole cache, do you know what will be the consequences of flushing a huge cache?